# Emacs python autocompletion

Tags: python, emacs

I've installed python-mode, pymacs and pycomplete+ from el-get on emacs24. But i am not able to get auto-completion for python in emacs.

Answer (score 12):

I'd recommend you to try [emacs-jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi). The author is really trying to bring the best Python autocompletion experience to Emacs. (It uses the [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) autocompletion library).

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to hook ropemacs up as an auto-complete source, but as far as I know it's not provided "by default" in any of these packages.  You might try this in your `.emacs`, [**this is a snippet I've used successfully**](http://dpaste.com/839051/)

From [**what I'm reading**](http://chrispoole.com/project/ac-python/) this package completion that's more simple to configure.

Comment: That dpaste.com link is broken. :(

Answer (score 0):

bzr branch lp:python-mode/components-python-mode

i.e. the development branch of python-mode.el
delivering an inlined Pymacs provides auto-completion right out of the box for me

Might conflict with an already installed Pymacs though